# Post Binary array to Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to POST form data which consists of few string variable and binary array. 
Below is the Model for the form data.

```
public class FileModel
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my Web API Controller.

```
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]FileModel media)
{      
    // Can I use ??
    byte[] requestFile = media.File;
    string requestFilePath = media.Path;

    //Process the above variables  
    return Ok();
}
```

I would like to know Can I use the following code to de-serialize the following code snippet to to read the values from the JSON payload including the binary data?

```
byte[] requestFile = media.File;
string requestFilePath = media.Path;
```

If Yes, Do I need to define any formatter class to get it working?

I normally use POSTMAN to test my RESTful endpoints. 
Is it possible to use POSTMAN still to POST binary array? May be not need to write my own client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a serializer to serialize complex objects (multiple fields) as content for a Http Request.

For your code snippet to read the object from the content you can use this:
`var requestContent = Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<FileModel>(GetJsonSerializer()).Result;`

Here's the serializer boilerplate code.

```
private JsonMediaTypeFormatter GetJsonSerializer()
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
        TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All
    };

    return new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = settings };
}
```

I'm not sure how to use POSTMAN to test this. A simple .net client would be:

```
var Client = new HttpClient();
Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("localhost"); //whatever your endpoint is
FileModel objectToSend = new FileModel();
var objectContent = new ObjectContent<FileModel>(objectToSend, GetJsonSerializer() );
var response = Client.PostAsync("uri", objectContent);
```

Comment: Hi Trisk, Thanks for your reply. I noticed my solution worked which direct use the FormBody Object. However when I used your solution with the formatter the requestContent  returns NULL.  var requestContent = Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<FileModel>(new MediaTypeFormatter[] { GetJsonSerializer() }).Result;

Comment: How did you construct the request? You might be able to remove the [FromBody] decoration. What does the Request object look like on the controller? Also in my sample code the FileModel object is constructed using the default constructor, it may set the object to null depending on how you made the class.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use POSTMAN to test binary file input.  Selecting the body tab, you can then pick the radio button "binary" and then choose file.